# How to appending elapsed seconds to the front of each line as it comes out of grep subprocess?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I am trying to append the elapsed seconds to each line that comes out of grep but I've hit a bit of a stump.

Another challenge is that I want to run other code while the top,grep processes to be running in the background. (So the implementation has to be non-blocking)

At the moment, I've been able to append the current time thanks to another answer on SO. In my sample code, I'm using 'perl' but it doesn't need to be although I cannot use gawk/ts or any other utilities/commands that do not come default on MacOS.

**Example of top output**

```
1227  Google Chrome He 0.0  00:06.59 13    1    151    58M   0B    51M   793  793  sleeping *0[5]     0.00000 0.00000    502 35702   2182  20972   10027   34224
```

**Example of desired output written to text file (Let's say 1.59 seconds passed)**

```
1.59 1227  Google Chrome He 0.0  00:06.59 13    1    151    58M   0B    51M   793  793  sleeping *0[5]     0.00000 0.00000    502 35702   2182  20972   10027   34224
```

**The next line in the file should have another top output with a later time (Let's say the next top command comes out of the buffer 2.13 seconds since the initial start time)**

```
2.13 1227  Google Chrome He 0.0  00:06.59 13    1    151    58M   0B    51M   793  793  sleeping *0[5]     0.00000 0.00000    502 35702   2182  20972   10027   34224
```

### My Code so far

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

start_time = timer()

f = open('file.txt', 'w')

top_proc = subprocess.Popen(['top'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
grep_proc = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '--line-buffered', ' Chrome'], stdin=top_proc.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Somehow append elapsed time since start_time to the grep output with this other process (it would be appending `timer() - start_time`) 
# Currently it just appends the current time
perl_proc = subprocess.Popen(['perl', '-pe', 'use POSIX strftime; print strftime "%H:%M:%S ", localtime'], stdin=grep_proc.stdout, stdout=f)

# Other code that runs for indefinite amount of time
other_code()

top_proc.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)

top_proc.wait()
grep_proc.wait()
perl_proc.wait()
f.close()
```

I'm using the timeit module because according to my research it is more accurate and my code is part of a script that is used to benchmark the memory usage of a Chrome process. I tried looking into the perl command but struggled to find any examples or similar use cases.

Is there a way I can repurpose my perl subprocess with to append the elapsed time? Or what other ways can I accomplish my goal?

#### Update

I tried doing `perl_proc = subprocess.Popen(['perl', '-pe', 'print "' + str(time.time() - start_time) + '" '], stdin=grep_proc.stdout, stdout=f)`, however it seems to only give me the elapsed time for initial line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program `ts` (time stamp) from the package GNU `moreutils` does exactly what you want.

Example:

```
for i in a b c d e; do echo $i; sleep 1; done | ts -s %.s
```

prints

```
0.000016 a
0.944115 b
1.974076 c
3.002769 d
4.031955 e
```

However, I agree with [Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68342266/6770384): Doing the timestamping in python would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using subprocesses to do things that are trivially available in Python?

```
import time
import subprocess

start_time = time.time()

f = open('file.txt', 'w')

top_proc = subprocess.Popen(['top'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in top_proc.stdout:
    if b'Chrome' in line:
        print( "%.3f" % (time.time() - start_time), line )
```

However, `top` was not designed to be called by this.  Your line will contain terminal control characters.

And, by the way, `awk` is certainly available in MacOS, as is the full normal Unix command set.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The reason I am using subprocess is because I want it to be able to run in the background so it doesn't block execution of other code.


Overview: 
1. Be running the top,grep, other process to append elapsed time, in the background
2. Execute some code to impact the performance of the process for a variable amount of time
3. End the processes and close the file